# Firefox XUL: default option/preferences values not working?

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I was able to finally get a checkbox in my Extension main page with the following XUL:

**src/content/options.xul**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vbox xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <setting type="bool" pref="extensions.tapiture-firefox.tapItButtonEnable" title="Enable Tap It Button" desc="Tap It button will appear on top left of every image upon hovering." />
</vbox>
```

I need the checkbox to be initially checked. It's default value needs to be true, I have the following line of code to set my default preferences :

**src/defaults/preferences/tapiture-firefox.js**

```
 pref("extensions.tapiture-firefox.tapItButtonEnable", true);
```

Doesn't work. Any ideas? I just need to set the default value for my options/preference checkbox.

Comment: Anyone? Programming extensions is a nightmare.

Comment: Do you actually use a `src/` "subfolder" in the extension/XPI? Is your add-on restartless or not?

Comment: I believe I am developing "Overlay extensions": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons

Comment: So, you don't have no `bootstrap.js`? What about my other question?

Comment: Here is my folder structure http://i.imgur.com/JBRPJCd.png

Comment: @nmaier any ideas? You're my final hope!!!

Comment: Nope, not really. The stuff you provided so far looks OK. If you provided me an Github repo or XPI, then maybe...

Comment: @nmaier i uploaded the xpi to my dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jc1m9qpu7w0ptnf/AAB2t6d7luvle9dp_RB6m63oa

Comment: I see you still need help man. Can you extract the xpi and upload it onto github please. I'll take a look.